# Reordering character triplets in Python

Tags: python-3.x, triplet

I've been trying to solve this homework problem for days, but can't seem to fix it. I started my study halfway through the first semester, so I can't ask the teacher yet and I hope you guys can help me. It's not for grades, I just want to know how.

I need to write a program that reads a string and converts the triplets `abc` into bca`. Per group of three you need to do this. For example`katzon`becomes`atkonz`.

The closest I've gotten is this:

```
string=(input("Give a string: "))

for i in range(0, len(string)-2):
    a = string[i]
    b = string[i + 1]
    c = string[i + 2]
    new_string= b, c, a
    i+=3
    print(new_string)
```

The output is:

```
('a', 't', 'k')
('t', 'z', 'a')
('z', 'o', 't')
('o', 'n', 'z')
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below converts for example "**abc**" to "**bca**". It works for any string containing triplets. Now, if input is "**abc**d", it is converted to "**bca**d". If you input "**katzon**", it is converted to "**atkonz**". This is what I understood from your question.

```
stringX = input()

# create list of words in the string
listX = stringX.split(" ")
listY = []

# create list of triplets and non-triplets
for word in listX:
    listY += [[word[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(word), 3)]]

# convert triplets, for example: "abc" -> "bca"
for listZ in listY:
    for item in listZ:
        if len(item)==3:
            listZ[listZ.index(item)] = listZ[listZ.index(item)][1:] + listZ[listZ.index(item)][0]
    listY[listY.index(listZ)] = "".join(listZ)

# create final string
stringY = " ".join(listY)
print(stringY)
```